# Nested JSON object array from given JSON array

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON array of the form

```
[{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'100','op':'cr'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'200','op':'dr'},
{'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'300','op':'cr'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'400','op':'dr'},
{'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'500','op':'cr'}]
```

I want the output as

```
[{'from':'a','to':'b','add':[{'100':'cr'},{'200':'dr'},{'300':'cr'}]},
 {'from':'c','to':'d','sub':[{'400':'dr'},{'500':'cr'}]}]
```

How to do it in Javascript/NodeJS?

Comment: What you're looking at is several *reduce* operations. You're also going to have to create (temporary) indexes on the `from` and `to` properties as they appear to be your desired *keys*. I wouldn't say this is a simple task and it seems highly specialised

Comment: Is that a typo `]]` at the end of the first piece of code?

Comment: @Phil Yeah that was a typo! Corrected it.

Comment: @JaromandaX There's no JSON in this question.

Comment: @YajneshRai please stop writing "JSON array". I edited your question for a good reason

Comment: @Brad it is a JSON array. Sorry for missing it out

Comment: @YajneshRai [there's no such thing as a JSON array or object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @JaromandaX Looking at the question history... I still see no JSON anywhere.  Sure, that's what was in the title, but the title was clearly wrong.  There's no JSON here to parse, so your comment was also incorrect.

Comment: @Brad You should not edit the question to introduce the word "flattening" when this is not really flattening, it's grouping. Also, let the OP fix his own incorrect reference to JSON. If he fails to do that after being so advised, then DV and/or CV if you want and move on.

Comment: @torazaburo Flattening, grouping, either seems appropriate to me.  In any case, rather than rolling back the edit, I wish you had further improved it with your suggestion.

Comment: @Brad No, I think flattening and grouping are different, and this is grouping. For instance, Underscore provides `_.flatten` and `_.groupBy`, which do two different things. I don't want to "improve" the title by inserting my own opinion about what the post is about. As far as the "JSON" issue goes, I went through a phase of editing posts, then through a phase of posting comments asking OP's to fix it, and now I'm in a phase of just not caring and DV'ing, or CV'ing, since it's a lost cause, and confusion about what JSON is usually implies other problems with the question or poster.

Comment: @torazaburo The question is clear, the title was wrong.  You wouldn't be inserting your opinion, you'd be making the question more understandable so that others answering can get right to the point.  If it's a lost cause, why bother doing anything?  it's true that the mountain of garbage questions on Stack Overflow is daunting, but even if you fix just one question out of a thousand bad ones, you're helping someone learn and having a real impact.  (Usually, anyway.  Of course there are plenty of people that just can't or won't learn.)

Answer (score 2):

Following code block has `resample` function which will solve your task.

```js
var sampleData = [
  {'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'100','op':'cr'},
  {'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'200','op':'dr'},
  {'from':'a','to':'b','type':'add','value':'300','op':'cr'},
  {'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'400','op':'dr'},
  {'from':'c','to':'d','type':'sub','value':'500','op':'cr'}
];

function resample(data) {
  var newData = [];
  var indexer = {};

  data.map(function(item, index) {
    //prepare indexer key
    var key = item.from + '_' + item.to;
    if (typeof indexer[key] === 'undefined') {
      indexer[key] = {from: item.from, to: item.to};
    }
    //adds or sub
    if (typeof indexer[key][item.type] === 'undefined') {
      indexer[key][item.type] = []
    }
    indexer[key][item.type].push({value: item.value, op: item.op})
    return [];
  })
  for( var key in indexer ){
    newData.push(indexer[key])
  }
  return newData;
}

var resampledData = resample(sampleData);

console.log(resampledData);
```

Be careful with `map` as all browser don't support this. simple for loops can replace the `map`

Comment: Umm, what browsers don't support `map`?

Comment: OP mentioned NodeJS so I don't think `Array.prototype.map` is a problem at all.

Comment: You should be more careful with that `for..in` loop

Comment: @Phil I think `for..in` have similar support as `Array.prototype.map`. Though `Object.keys` and `map` can fulfill the replacement of `for..in` by `Object.keys(indexer).map( function(key){ newData.push(indexer[key]) })`

Answer (score 1):

This uses some ES6 arrow functions and object literal shorthand but you said you're using NodeJS so it should be ok

```js
let a = [{"from":"a","to":"b","type":"add","value":"100","op":"cr"},{"from":"a","to":"b","type":"add","value":"200","op":"dr"},{"from":"a","to":"b","type":"add","value":"300","op":"cr"},{"from":"c","to":"d","type":"sub","value":"400","op":"dr"},{"from":"c","to":"d","type":"sub","value":"500","op":"cr"}];

let tmp = a.reduce((map, row) => {
  // create a key hash of "from" and "to"
  let key = [row.from, row.to].join(',');
  
  // the value to append to the "type" array
  let valueObj = { [row.value]: row.op };
  
  // ensure map[key][row.type] is an array
  map[key] = Object.assign({ [row.type]: [] }, map[key]);
  
  // add the value
  map[key][row.type].push(valueObj);
  return map;
}, Object.create(null));

let out = Object.keys(tmp).map(key => {
  // re-create the "from" and "to" properties from the key "hash"
  let k = key.split(',');
  
  return Object.assign({
    from: k[0],
    to: k[1]
  }, tmp[key]);
});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will do . This can be improved.

```
function parseInput(input) {
    var result = [];
    input.forEach(
        function(data) {
            var subData = {};
            subData[data.value] = data.op;
            var index = getMatchingIndex(result, data);
            if (index == -1) {
                var typeData = {};
                typeData[data.type] = [subData];

                var resData = {};
                resData.from = data.from;
                resData.to = data.to;
                resData[data.type] = [];
                resData[data.type].push(subData);
                result.push(resData);
            } else {
                result[index][data.type].push(subData);
            }
        }
    );
    return result;
}

function getMatchingIndex(result, data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i].from === data.from &&
            result[i].to === data.to &&
            result[i].hasOwnProperty(data.type))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

var input = [{
    'from': 'a',
    'to': 'b',
    'type': 'add',
    'value': '100',
    'op': 'cr'
}, {
    'from': 'a',
    'to': 'b',
    'type': 'add',
    'value': '200',
    'op': 'dr'
}, {
    'from': 'a',
    'to': 'b',
    'type': 'add',
    'value': '300',
    'op': 'cr'
}, {
    'from': 'c',
    'to': 'd',
    'type': 'sub',
    'value': '400',
    'op': 'dr'
}, {
    'from': 'c',
    'to': 'd',
    'type': 'sub',
    'value': '500',
    'op': 'cr'
}];

JSON.stringify(parseInput(input));
```

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: @torazaburo pass the input data to `parseInput` function and you'll get the result